# Mock window properties in Javascript jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have an object that require `JSON`. The object populates an `isSupported` function and i'm trying to write a test for it.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    this.myFactory = function() {};

    this.myFactory.isSupported = function() {
        return !!this.JSON;
    };
}).call(window);
```

If i just set `window.JSON = false` for a specific test than all other tests obviously fail because they need that.

```
describe('Test IsSupported', function() {

    it('Should return false if no JSON', function() {
        window.JSON = undefined;
        expect(myFactory.isSupported()).toEqual(false);
    });

});
```

How can I test this function in a context of a mock window ?

Answer (score 0):

I would inject window in your factory's constructor, so that the code is testable, while still usable in the browser:

**factory.js**:

```
module.exports = function(window){

    return {
        isSupported: function() {
            return !!window.JSON;
        }
    }

};
```

**factory.spec.js**:

```
var Factory = require('./factory');
fdescribe('Test IsSupported', function() {

    it('Should return false if no JSON', function() {
        var window = {JSON: false};
        var factory = Factory(window);

        expect(factory.isSupported()).toBeFalsy();
    });

    it('Should return true if yes JSON', function() {
        var window = {JSON: true};
        var factory = Factory(window);

        expect(factory.isSupported()).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```